# What is the structure of SocialEngine based on Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, module, structure, socialengine

I want to know what the structure of Social Engine is. For example if I want to go to a page that the URL of that page is "http://example.com/stores/products", how can I find the controllers, models, views of?
When I go to direction application I see these:

```
languages
libraries
modules
plugins
settings
themes
widgets
```

and when I go into modules I see all modules added to the site including these:

```
Sitestore
Sitestorealbum
Sitestoreform
Sitestoreproduct
Siteverify
Sitevideo
```

and so on...

and when I go into Sitestore as an example, I see these:

```
Api
controllers
externals
Form
Model
Plugin
settings
View
views
widgets
```

But even now I don't know where to find the file I need related to the URL mentioned above.

Just tell me if you want to know what's inside each file.

Appreciation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the controller and action name from `manifest.php` under `modules/XYZ/settings/manifest.php`.

Example, `/stores/products`

Go to modules`/Sitestoreproduct/settings/manifest.php`

Here you can see the `slug_` of Store module and Products module.

For core modules, you will find the url structure in the `/settings/manifest.php` only, but in third party modules, SEAO and others they have extended the submodules by making it dynamic.

Hope it helps you to understand.